# Objective c: binary operations with Integers?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, binary, bit-shift

I have **BASIC** logical question about the following code snippet:

```
1     uint64_t RMTileKey(RMTile tile)
2    {
3            uint64_t zoom = (uint64_t) tile.zoom & 0xFFLL; // 8bits, 256 levels
4            uint64_t x = (uint64_t) tile.x & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits
5            uint64_t y = (uint64_t) tile.y & 0xFFFFFFFLL;  // 28 bits
6    
7       uint64_t key = (zoom << 56) | (x << 28) | (y << 0);
8    
9       return key;
10    }
```

The return value key is an unsigned integer. 
I am very confused now, because i dont understand what is happening in line 3(4,5). The operator & does what with my uint64_t. I guess it is converting to a hex-value ?
And then in line 7 i shift from bit 0 to 27 (28 to 56 ...) and merge theses hex-based numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

line 3: `zoom` has all the bits except 0 to 7 clear: `0000...000zzzzzzzz` 8 bits

line 4: `x` has all the bits except 0 to 27 clear: `0000...000xxxx...xxxx`; 28 bits

line 5: `y` has all the bits except 0 to 27 clear: `0000...000yyyy...yyyy`; 28 bits

line 7: the bits are rearranged to make a single 64-bit value:

```
         ,--------------------- bit 56
        /          ,----------- bit 28
       /          /          ,- bit 0
zzzzzzzzxxxx...xxxxyyyy...yyyy
zoom<<56   x<<28      y<<0
```

Comment: Love the layout and the explanation. +1

Answer (score 0):

First - 
`&` is the binary AND operator.
`|` is the binary OR operator.

1. Line 3 will assign the LSB of `tile.zoom` to `zoom` (which is modulu 0x100)
2. Line 4 will assign the 28 least significant bits of `tile.x` to `x` (which is modulu 0x10000000)
3. Line 5 as line 4.
4. Line 7 will construct the key variable by putting all the above variable in different bits(offsets) of `key`.

Comment: I know that & is the AND operator and | Or for binaries and i understand now what you are saying about line 3,4,5. But why i use the OR operator in line 7 to put them into different bits? How is it working?